# Jquery validation radio button

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I want to validate my radio button here is my code:

```
<form id="#FormSend">
    <fieldset>
        <input class="required" name="myoptions[]" type="radio" value="label 1" /> 
        <label> Label 1</label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input class="required" name="myoptions[]" type="radio" value="label 2" /> 
        <label> Label 2</label>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

As for my header  i have this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#FormSend").validate({
        rules: {
            'myoptions[]':{required:true}
        }
    });
});
```

It' doesn't validate it at all.. please help

Comment: This  seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/54Q5Q/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a few things:

- Where is `#FormSend`? Is it the `id` of the `form`?
- Do you have jQuery and validation script included? and is the jQuery getting loaded in first?

Comment: added the form tag sorry about that

Comment: and what about the scripts? You have both scripts loading?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your browser, use the javascript console to check for javascript errors. ie9 and ie8 - press f12 to get into the developers toolbar, click on Script and then Start Debugging. Refresh the page, and you'll see any javascript errors.

Firefox - download firebug

Chrome - (windows) Press Ctrl+Shift+J, click on Scripts

Safari - it's slightly more complicated - http://mactips.info/2010/07/use-safari-5s-web-inspector